# RestKit setObjectMapping issues; forKeyPath succeeds where forResourcePathPattern fails

Tags: ios, json, restkit

Very confusing times here adding various requests to a project in development. For two objects so far `setObjectMapping:forResourcePathPattern:` works fine. These have resource patterns like `@"customer/login/"` and `@"customer/getDuckStatus/"`. A query that fails to create an object with correct mapping is `@"customer/getPondsForDuck/"`

```
// this define is used for object mapping and for creating the query, 
// it can't be a mismatch
#define kResourcePathDuckPond @"customer/getPondsForDuck/"
```

The only difference I can see in the queries is that the keypath in the returned JSON is nil for the first two queries that work. When the keypath is nil and `forResourcePathPattern` is used to set object mapping, `objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects` (`RKObjectLoaderDelegate` method) receives a valid object with correct mapping. When the keypath is non-nil, using `forResourcePathPattern` always sends `didLoadObjects:` a nil object.

Using

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:duckMapping
                                           forResourcePathPattern:kResourcePathDuckPond];
```

fails. Using

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:duckMapping
                                                       forKeyPath:@"ponds"];
```

(where "ponds" is the keypath given in the returned JSON) works fine.

Is that the rule, `forResourcePathPattern` will fail unless keypath is nil? I'd like to have all my objects recognized the same way. While I can get it working I don't like using key path for one query and resource path for others. I wanted to use `forResourcePathPattern` for everything since I don't have control of the API and some queries return a keypath while some don't.